# Как создать label при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `PushButton` появлялся `label`. Как это сделать?

Я хочу написать игру *wordle*, вот код, в котором есть кнопка начать игру и `label` с текстом "я загадал слово", который должен появляться по нажатию на кнопку.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(750, 750)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 70, 300, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 0);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(245, 180, 260, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 0);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate 
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Wordle - Game")) 
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "НАЧАТЬ ИГРУ")) 
    self.label.setText(_translate("Form", " Я ЗАГАДАЛ СЛОВО"))
```

Comment: pythoner, покажите код, который у вас уже написан.

Comment: Я только начинаю работать с pyqt и qt designer, код ещё не начинал писать. Мне нужно узнать как сделать так, чтобы по нажатии на кнопку появлялся label в заданных координатах.

Comment: pythoner, вам надо попробовать что-то написать, например, попробуйте написать приложение, в котором есть кнопка, которую вы собираетесь нажимать. а label уже потом как-то пристроем.

Comment: S. Nick, изменил вопрос, добавил код

Answer (score 0):

После того как вы получили код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*,
cоздайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from random import randint, choices
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(750, 750)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 70, 300, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 0);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(245, 180, 260, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 0);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.retranslateUi(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate 
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Wordle - Game")) 
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "НАЧАТЬ ИГРУ")) 
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", " Я ЗАГАДАЛ СЛОВО"))
        

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):               
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # создайте список каких-то слов
        self.words = ['первое', 'второе', 'третье', 'привет', 'мир']
        
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        # Кнопка излучает сигнал clicked(), когда она активируется мышью, пробелом 
        # или сочетанием клавиш. Подключитесь к этому сигналу, чтобы выполнить действие кнопки.
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button)
        
    def clicked_button(self):        
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices
        self.word_new = choices(self.words)[0]

        self.label.setText(self.word_new)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 
    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]